# mmenu opens/shows blank page

Tags: android, jquery, mmenu

I am struggling to resolve an issue I have with jquery mmenu

I am currently testing on Android and have configured the setup as per the demo using

```
<a href="#menu">open menu</a>
```

setup with `$('menu').mmenu();`

I have also tried (as suggested)

```
$("#menu").trigger( "open" );
```

(using a different href on the link.

Can anyone suggest how to debug or a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue - it appears that having

```
// DON'T copy, this is the problem not solution //
```

`overflow:scroll !important;

height: auto !important;`

on the body tag of the page (required to override issues being caused elsewhere) caused the page to shrink to 0px in height and force the page to appear blank.

Hope this helps anyone else.